# How to make sure a variable is an object

Tags: javascript, variables, design-patterns

I have been programming Javascript for a little while now, and still am not quite sure if I am being too lazy or not.
I have a lot of:

```
if( typeof( something) === 'undefined' ){
  // ..
}
```

However, sometimes it just becomes too verbose. For example, now I am doing:

```
var redirectURLs = hotplate.get('hotCoreAuth/redirectURLs/success') || {};
```

That's because in the following lines I am treating redirectURLs as an object, although it might not be defined at all (the function might well return `undefined`).

Is there a "best practice" cheatsheet? Is what I wrote above just too lazy? It's just that the alternative is cumbersome:

```
var redirectURLs = hotplate.get('hotCoreAuth/redirectURLs/success');
if( typeof( redirectURLs ) === 'undefined' ){
  redirectURLs = {}
}
```

I realise that the shortcut is less robust, but then again, people will either have set that value, or not.

Ideas?

Merc.

Comment: I tend to add a `NS.isDefined(test_var, [default_if_not_defined])` helper function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using your "shortcut", that is equivalent to the following:

```
var redirectURLs = hotplate.get('hotCoreAuth/redirectURLs/success');
if (!redirectURLs) redirectURLs = {};
```

The specification ([ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/ECMA-262.pdf)) states that the logical OR operator (`||`) tests whether the first expression (in this case, the function call) coerces to true or not -- if it coerces to true, return the first expression, else return the second one.

It also states what coerces to true and false ([§9.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) - note that this isn't given verbatim):

> **False:**
>
> - The numbers +0, -0, and NaN
> - The empty string (`""`)
> - `false`
> - `null`
> - `undefined`
>
> **True:** everything else (including stuff like `new Boolean(false)`)

So, if you don't mind letting most numbers, strings or the value `true` through, then the logical OR "shortcut" would be OK. Note that your "verbose" code might break if `redirectURLs` is null:

```
var redirectURLs = null;
if (typeof redirectURLs === 'undefined') {
  redirectURLs = {};
}
redirectURLs.test = '1'; // TypeError: Cannot set property 'test' of null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to deal with objects from an external API (I'm assuming you don't have control over the `hotplate` library) you could just wrap each function call to cast to an object.

```
function getHotplateUri(uri){
    // Probably good to validate the URI format
    var redirectURLs = hotplate.get(uri);
    if( typeof( redirectURLs ) === 'undefined' ){
      redirectURLs = {}
    }
    return redirectURLs
}
```

Comment: The wrapper suggestion is ok, but other than that I don't agree with this code at all, it's very smelly. Why would you suggest to validate the `uri`? Why is `hotplate` not a dependency?

Comment: Why validate the URI: to fail fast for any consumers of the wrapper. Why is hot plate not a dependency: agreed, this should be the case.

Answer (score 0):

With `typeof`, which is an operator (no need for parentheses) you check for *existence* of the variable. The short-circuit operator `||` assumes that the variable already exists (has been declared) and checks if its value is falsy (undefined, null, empty string, zero...).

So with this in mind, in your case using `typeof` is redundant because you're testing the returned value of a method of the object `hotplate` that already exists. As you said:

> ...the function might well return `undefined`

`"undefined"` is a type, while `undefined` is a pre-defined value (of type `"undefined"`). It gets assigned to variables when they're hoisted until the assignment occurs. If there's no assignment then the variable is declared but has a value of `undefined`. Also functions that return nothing return `undefined`.

So `typeof undefined === 'undefined' // true`

Comment: Is there a nice, "accepted" document out there that explains when it is OK to use the shortcut, why, etc.?